# Flutter Web - Can't change GET request's referer in header

Tags: flutter, http-headers, flutter-web, chopper

I'm trying to call a GET request using `chopper` with a custom referer. But everytime it calls, it only uses the default referer. I added a custom header and it still works

[image: Set up request with custom header with custom referer]

[image: The referer does not change]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change `referrer` programmatically. please refer this web page : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

> A forbidden header name is the name of any HTTP header that cannot be
> modified programmatically; specifically,

Comment: OMG. I'm a mobile developer so I have no idea about this. Do you have any "tweak" or "cheat" to do this ? Since I only run this web on local scope.

Comment: actually I dont know, sorry.

Comment: If it's just for development purposes you could modify it with a proxy or an extension e.g. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-modify-headers/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa